# Why are there so many different ways to use new operator in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I've just read the [new operator explanation on the cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new/). The page gives an example to demonstrate four different ways of using new operator as following:

```
// operator new example
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

struct myclass {myclass() {cout <<"myclass constructed\n";}};

int main () {

   int * p1 = new int;
// same as:
// int * p1 = (int*) operator new (sizeof(int));

   int * p2 = new (nothrow) int;
// same as:
// int * p2 = (int*) operator new (sizeof(int),nothrow);

   myclass * p3 = (myclass*) operator new (sizeof(myclass));
// (!) not the same as:
// myclass * p3 = new myclass;
// (constructor not called by function call, even for non-POD types)

   new (p3) myclass;   // calls constructor
// same as:
// operator new (sizeof(myclass),p3)

   return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice of using
   new operator?
2. Is `myclass* p3 = new myclass` equivalent to `myclass* p3 = new myclass()`?

Comment: There is no "best practice" - you have to know what you are doing. Or you could not use new at all - many useful C++ programs can and should be written without using it.

Comment: This thread should answer your second question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Comment: In when you truly need dynamic allocation, do use a smart pointer.

Comment: @Neil, well, I mean the guideline to determine which usage of new operator to take.

Comment: @xiao I suspect that english is not your first language, so I'll rephrase - there is no general guideline, it depends what your code is intended (by you) to do.

Comment: C++ isn't a simple language. If he thinks this is confusing, wait 'till he discovers that it is possible to create a protected abstract virtual base pure virtual private destructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because they have different purposes. If you didn't want `new` to throw `std::bad_alloc` on failure, you would use `nothrow`. If you wanted to allocate your objects in existing storage, you would use placement new … if you want raw, uninitialized memory, you would invoke `operator new` directly and cast the result to the target type.

**The plain standard usage of `new` in 99% of all cases is `MyClass* c = new MyClass()`;**

To your second question: the `new Object()` vs. `new Object` forms are not generally equal. See [this question and the responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) for the details. But that *really* is nitpicking. Usually they are equivalent, but to be on the safe side always pick `new Object()`; Note that, in this particular sample they are equal because `MyClass` doesn't have any members, so strictly speaking the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Perhaps I should correct myself: the plain standard way of using `new` in a C++ statement.

Answer (score 2):

1) Several of these are used only in specific, unusual situations. The plain old traditional one is best, most of the time anyway:

```
X * x = new X();
```

2) Yes, they are. If the constructor has no arguments, the parentheses are optional. If you're declaring an automatic variable -- i.e.,

```
X x;
```

then you *must* omit the parentheses, or it's a function declaration! As a result, many people will tell you to omit them in the `new` expression as well. That's a good practice, I think, but I'm just used to including them.

Comment: `new X` is not the same as `new X()` for PODs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "best practice", you need them in different situations. For example, most people just want to call `new x()` to allocate some memory and create the object. However, sometimes you're in situations where you don't want an exception thrown in case `new` fails, so you call `new (nothrow)` instead to get a null back.

If you already have some memory allocated but need to create an object, you use "placement new" by calling `new (p3) x`.

In the rare case where you need to use a class's memory allocator but not actually create an object, you use the `(myclass*) operator new (sizeof(myclass))` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my recommendations:

1. Prefer not to use `new`; pass by
   reference when possible. (Avoids memory leaks).
2. Use `operator new`:  `x = new X(); // Remember to use delete`
3. Prefer `std::vector` to array `new`:
   `x = new X()[quantity]; // Remember to use delete []`
4. Don't use *placement* `new` unless
   you absolutely know the reasons.

In general, placement new is used to allocate from specific addresses or a special memory pool.  This is an advanced topic.